# switch from back camera to front camera i get null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Now I am developing camera application.When I launch my app first it display back camera and I have one button when I click that button it will turn to front camera.on that time I get error null pointer Exception.but when I run front camera individually it display front camera perfectly.

```
This is my java code.

 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       // getAspectRatio();

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

 Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
            }});


        front=(Button)findViewById(R.id.front);
        front.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                {
                    Intent font_intent=new Intent(AndroidCamera.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(font_intent);
                }

            }
        });

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

            @Override
            public void onShutter() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){



             @Override

             public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) 
             {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length); 


                Bitmap mBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),currenteffect);
                Bitmap  newgerresized=getResizedBitmap(mBitmap2, bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight());

                Bitmap map = applyOverlayEffect(newgerresized, bitmapPicture);

                String fieName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();   
                SaveImage(fieName, 100,map);
              camera.startPreview();

             }

@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(previewing)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            try 
            {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {

            try{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             camera = Camera.open();
             mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
            }catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }finally
            {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            previewing = false;
        }

for front this is my java code

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
             id=findFrontFacingCamera(); 
             Log.d("TestLedActivity","L'id trovato e': "+id);
             camera = Camera.open(id+1); 
        } else{
            Log.d("TestLedActivity","La versione e' froyo");
            camera = Camera.open();
        }

        preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
                previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
                previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

                i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                currenteffect=R.drawable.water;
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.water);
                newgerresized=getResizedBitmap(mBitmap, width,height);
                bi=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAlpha(100);
                canvas=new Canvas(bi);
                canvas.setBitmap(bi);
                canvas.drawBitmap(newgerresized, 0, 0, paint); 
                i.setImageBitmap(bi);


      }

      public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) 
        {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), null, options);


        int srcWidth = bm.getWidth();
        int srcHeight = bm.getHeight();

        int desiredWidth = newWidth;
        int desiredHeight = newHeight;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        while(srcWidth / 2 > desiredWidth)
        {
            srcWidth /= 2;
            srcHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

        float desiredWidthScale = (float) desiredWidth / srcWidth;
        float desiredHeightScale = (float) desiredHeight / srcHeight;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap sampledSrcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), null, options);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(desiredWidthScale, desiredHeightScale);

        matrix.postRotate(Orientation);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(sampledSrcBitmap, 0, 0, sampledSrcBitmap.getWidth(), sampledSrcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
   return bmp;

}

      @Override  
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();   



      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (inPreview) {
          camera.stopPreview();
        }

        camera.release();
        camera=null;
        inPreview=false;

        super.onPause();
      }




      private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
         int idCamera=0;
            // Look for front-facing camera, using the Gingerbread API.
            // Java reflection is used for backwards compatibility with pre-Gingerbread APIs.
            try {
                Class<?> cameraClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
                Object cameraInfo = null;
                Field field = null;
                int cameraCount = 0;
                Method getNumberOfCamerasMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getNumberOfCameras" );
                if ( getNumberOfCamerasMethod != null ) {
                    cameraCount = (Integer) getNumberOfCamerasMethod.invoke( null, (Object[]) null );
                }
                Class<?> cameraInfoClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo");
                if ( cameraInfoClass != null ) {
                    cameraInfo = cameraInfoClass.newInstance();
                }
                if ( cameraInfo != null ) {
                    field = cameraInfo.getClass().getField( "facing" );
                }
                Method getCameraInfoMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getCameraInfo", Integer.TYPE, cameraInfoClass );
                if ( getCameraInfoMethod != null && cameraInfoClass != null && field != null ) {
                    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                        getCameraInfoMethod.invoke( null, camIdx, cameraInfo );
                        int facing = field.getInt( cameraInfo );
                        if ( facing == 1 ) { // Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
                            try {
                                Method cameraOpenMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "open", Integer.TYPE );
                                if ( cameraOpenMethod != null ) {
                                    Log.d("TestLedActivity","Id frontale trovato: "+camIdx);
                                    //camera = (Camera) cameraOpenMethod.invoke( null, camIdx );
                                    idCamera=camIdx;
                                }
                            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                Log.e("TestLedActivity", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Ignore the bevy of checked exceptions the Java Reflection API throws - if it fails, who cares.
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e        ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "ClassNotFoundException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( NoSuchMethodException e         ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "NoSuchMethodException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( NoSuchFieldException e          ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "NoSuchFieldException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( IllegalAccessException e        ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "IllegalAccessException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( InvocationTargetException e     ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "InvocationTargetException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( InstantiationException e        ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "InstantiationException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( SecurityException e             ) {Log.e("TestLedActivity", "SecurityException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}

            if ( camera == null ) {
                Log.d("TestLedActivity","Devo aprire la camera dietro");
                // Try using the pre-Gingerbread APIs to open the camera.
                idCamera=0;
            }

            return idCamera;
        }



      private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                             Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result=null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
          if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
              result=size;
            }
            else {
              int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
              int newArea=size.width*size.height;

              if (newArea>resultArea) {
                result=size;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        return(result);
      }


      SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
          }
          catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                  "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            Toast
              .makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                   int format, int width,
                                   int height) {
          Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
          Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                                              parameters);

          if (size!=null) {
            //parameters.set("camera-id", 0);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);      
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            inPreview=true;
          }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          // no-op
        }
      };
    }

please help me
```

Comment: please post the stack trace of your exception

Comment: 12-22 12:14:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 12:14:32.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.outthinking.cameraoverlay/com.outthinking.cameraoverlay.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

 android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:317)